# CentOS 6.6 ignores iptables nat rules

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, nat

I try to use iptables nat to forward incoming TCP traffic to another computer. I use following rules within nat table:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.137.1:8888 
-A POSTROUTING -o eth3 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.198
```

I expect that the 1st rule will forward incoming TCP traffic on 8888 port to another computer (192.168.137.1) 8888 port, and that the second rule will replace 192.168.137.1 address in response TCP traffic with 192.168.0.198.
However, it never happens, port forwarding doesn't work, clients can not connect to 192.168.0.198. What is the reason?

Comment: please can you try to provide a network scheme of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have 2 computers; the 1st IP address is 192.168.0.198, then 2nd one is 192.168.137.1. I want to forward any incoming TCP traffic from 192.168.0.198:8888 to 192.168.137.1:8888. 192.168.137.1 has server program that listens 8888 port.